# Impersonate User And Encrypt File

Tags: windows, winapi, encryption, impersonation

I want to encrypt a file/folder using EncryptFile function while Impersonating another user, I gave the other user Full Control over the file, but I still get Access Denied.

```
    HANDLE hUser;

    if (LogonUser(L"test", L".", L"123", LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hUser) == TRUE) {
        ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hUser);

        if (EncryptFile(dir_to_enc) == FALSE) {
            printf("%d\n", GetLastError()); // I get 5 - Access Denied
        }

        RevertToSelf();

        CloseHandle(hUser);
    }
```

edit:

when I change the fourth parameter of LogonUser from LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK to LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, the error code changes to 87, ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER.

Answer (score 1):

[image]I don't know why but when I change the dwLogonType to LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH everything works correctly!

It seems that it is used when we need to do something on behalf of the user.
but other types are not directly intended for that.

Comment: If I understand rightly, encryption (and decryption) requires the user's credentials, which it gets from the cache.  You'll note that under `LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK` it specifically says that that option does not cache the credentials.  (But I don't know why the interactive option doesn't work.  Perhaps because it generates a UAC limited token?)